# Javascript opening new window with external URL (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, external-url

I have some simple lines of code:

```
that.click(function(){
    window.open($('.linkBox input').val());       
});
```

Assuming I'm redirecting to google.com,
whenever a new window is opened, the URL is: "my/project/url/http://www.google.com"

Basically whatever URL is inputted, it gets appended to the end of my project's URL. How can I avoid this?

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be happening. Can you double-check the value?

Comment: Looks like your code is fine. Issue will happen when there is no `http://` in the user inputted URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem could be the missing `http://` in the URL, try this code

```
that.click(function(){        
        var url = $('.linkBox input').val();
        if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
            url = 'http://' + url;
        }
        window.open(url);
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/BPBev/1/